# How do I prove that span(W) will be a subset of span(V)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Question: For any two sets of vectors V = {v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>,v<sub>3</sub>} and W = {w<sub>1</sub>, w<sub>2</sub>} where W is a subset of span(V), it must be true that span(W) will also be a subset of span(V).

What steps do I show to prove this is true?

Comment: Span(V) is a (sub-)vector space F, hence for any subset W of F, span(W) is a subset of F.

Comment: $Span(W)$ is the smallest vector space that contains $W$. Since $W\subset Span(V)$, then $Span(V)$ is a vector space that contain $W$. Therefore $Span(W)$ is a subspace of $Span(V)$.... In particular, $Span(W)$ is a subset of $Span(V)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the steps needed to prove this, what you can do is first write $w_1$ and $w_2$ as a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ (note that you can do this since $W\subseteq span(V)$). Then take any element $z = c_1w_1+c_2w_2 \in span(W)$, and see if you can write it as a linear combination of the $v_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the basic fact that linear combinations of linear combinations of vectors from some set $S$ can also be written directly as linear combinations of vectors from $S$ (here with $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$).